# SSIS flat files to database table

Tags: sql-server, csv, ssis

I want to merge 10 text files (tab delimited) and import them into a Sql Server database using SSIS. Anyone has a clue how to do this?

Comment: Anything specific to your case that Google isn't helping you with?

Comment: No but had time constraints, sorry for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flat File Source...Merge Join Transformation...OLE DB Command (if using a stored procedure) or OLE DB Destination.  Thats the most logical answer for you considering the lack of detail from your question.

Comment: Thanks, I used multi flat file source, script editor, ole db.